# Best way to make sturdy Fence post for aluminum sign?

Tags: outdoor, metal, post, pressure-treated

I'm looking at putting some posts up for No-Smoking signs at a local club frequented by a couple hundred kids a weekend + their families.  One guy recommended Treated lumber, but I heard it'll eat into Aluminum Signs.  I'm guessing the cheap metal fence posts from Lowes or Home Depot will be prone to bending.

What would be the best thing to use?  If it's metal, what specs specifically should I be looking for?  It's outdoors, so I'm assuming I'd be capping metal, or thinking I'd paint the treated white.  Either way I'm planning on a 2 foot hole with concrete for the post to sit in so any kids hanging on it don't pull it out or over.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Prone to bending by what? Either option is fine unless they'll be subject to abuse (you can just isolate the aluminum from the PT wood). If so, you need to explain that better. It takes a lot of force to bend a 2-1/2" steel pipe.

Comment: Wall thickness of a 16 guage pipe is 0.060" through 0.065". So the 8' Terminal posts at lowes are that thickness?  I'm just imagining goofy teenagers hanging on it sidewise while goofing off waiting for their parents to pick them up.  https://www.lowes.com/pd/Common-2-3-8-in-x-8-ft-Actual-2-37-in-x-2-37-in-x-8-ft-Galvanized-Steel-Chain-Link-Fence-Terminal-Post/999990216.

Comment: I can't see kids bending those unless they're trying to do so, and if they are you can't prevent damage unless you use plenty of concrete.

Comment: well as I said, If I'm going to do it, I'm planning on setting it well in the ground with concrete, are you saying I should fill the post with concrete as well and tamp it down?  

The area is kind of rural, so I feel like sooner or later, something goofy might happen.  If someone is hellbent on destruction I can't stop that, but part of being kids is less than ideal decision making at times.

Comment: the wood post is the way to go (IMO), the steel will be bent by bored kids, Im also not following how aluminium will be damaged/eaten into by the wood post?   -- unless its high enough, i am sure the nice bendable aluminium sign will be bent way before they play with the post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-1/2" Steel EMT (Electrical Metal Tubing) is a good thing to use for signposts. Cheap, strong, galvanized for corrosion resistance and you can get simple little snap-on caps for the top to keep water out.

Comment: I agree, but how is it better than the fenceposts that have already been rejected?